# Cryptography reference not working for Xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, cryptography, xamarin

[image]

I have added the PCL Crypto package in my project and I am trying to use the Cryptography service in MVVMCross..but it is showing up..as in the image.

Any help?

Comment: You mean it has turned red? Nice color. Any error with that?

Comment: No..its not about..color. I am not able to use those references even if I use the PCLCrypto Packages

Answer (score -1):

`PCLCrypto` doesn't provide the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace. Its APIs are exposed in `PCLCrypto.WinRTCrypto`.